# Show plot on R-Studio terminal

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

do you guys know how to display an R plot in a terminal/console instead of showing it on plot viewers?

I've recently working to integrate R with external tools, and somehow the only function works is to returns all the value shown up in the console result. Thus, I need some sort of workaround to be able to post a plot in the external tools.

**Thanks in advance!**
[image]

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not possible. The reason is that the plot needs a graphic device.

The terminal (and R console) is a text-based device.

What you *can* do, is use the image-format files as graphic device. Here, you have a multitude of choices, such as PNG, BMP, JPEG. In R, look up `?png`.